# Magento 2 - what is the current theme?

Tags: magento2, admin, theme

I'm working on a M2 store and I want to set the Luma theme from the admin to do some debugging. The way M2 themes are set is waaaay different than M1. I'm looking at the **CONTENT > Design > Configuration** section, but I can't figure out what is the current theme. The store has multiple websites and store views and multiple themes.

Anyone can shed some light, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see theme(s) and/or make changes, go to `Content->Design->Themes`.  From there, you can select each one to change the fallback settings, among other things.

The part that (I think) you are looking for is under `Content->Design->Configuration`:

[image]

Here you will see the different websites and store-views.  Select `Edit` on the 2nd-to-last column of your desired scope, and you can change the applied theme, as well as make theme-related changes:

[image]